# TextView does not add new lines

Tags: java, android

I've got:

```
class ccProfile{
    private String issuer, name, cardnum, expire;
    private Double bal, limit;
    //getters and setters
```

in creditCard.java. In my main activity, I used a switch statement to just set them all from an array I had. Im trying to print them all to a textview, but I can't seem to get them to print on an individual line....

Example of setting data:

```
ccProfile ccObj1 = new ccProfile();
// . . . . . . . . 
case 2:
    ccObj1.setCardnum(data[z]);
    z++;
    break;
```

Here is how I'm printing:

```
tv1.setText(ccObj1.getIssuer() + "\n");
tv1.setText(ccObj1.getName()+"\n");
tv1.setText(ccObj1.getCardnum()+"\n");
tv1.setText(ccObj1.getExpire()+"\n");
sD = Double.toString(ccObj1.getBal());
tv1.setText(sD+"\n");
sD = Double.toString(ccObj1.getLimit());
tv1.setText(sD+"\n");
```

All its doing is printing the last value, what gives?

Comment: setText () clears the value of the textview and replaces it with whatever you supply as the argument.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known that... Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which sets the new text and replaces any existing text. It overwrittes your text with every call. You are looking for [append()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which appends text.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call setText () you are erasing what was there before. If you want to set the value of the TextView to all of the strings try using a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("string 1 \n");
sb.append("string 2");
tv1.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

setText() overrides all the previous contents of your TextArea.

```
    tv1.setText(ccObj1.getIssuer() + "\n" 
      +ccObj1.getName()+"\n"
      +ccObj1.getCardnum()+"\n" 
      +ccObj1.getExpire()+"\n"
      +Double.toString(ccObj1.getBal())+"\n"
      +Double.toString(ccObj1.getLimit()+"\n");
```

Will give you your desired result